# Import qcow2 image to docker hub

Tags: docker

I have prebuild ubuntu14.0.4.1 qcow2 image . I followed the following instruction for importing it to docker hub
Used virt-tar-out to convert it tar file

```
sudo virt-tar-out -a /tmp/ubuntu.qcow2 / - | gzip --best > ubuntu.tar.gz
cat ubuntu.tar.gz | sudo docker import - repo:tag
```

I get the image id

Now when I try run a conatiner from the image I get following error

> Error response from daemon: No command specified

If the I give the command along with docker run command

> exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory 
>   Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 
>   c2d0ce1a4bfd9f4784edad53b3669e736f1442b2ba208294b00f242d07dc2208: [8] System error: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory

None of the commands are working.

- Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d

Thanks
Preeti

Answer (score 0):

Docker import can only handle plain tar files. No compression. And only from a docker export, not a bunch of files in a tar file.

You could start a stock ubuntu 14 image in Docker and then use `docker cp` to copy your own files into a running container, then export that.